# How to do Linq Many to Many join with or without navigation properties

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, linq

this question has been asked several times on stackoverflow, and I have read through atleast half a dozen of those, but I can't get my head around a simple many to many linq join query. This is my database EDMX[image]

I'm simply trying to populate a WPF datagrid with the list of students, along with each student's subjects.

Now I know we can simply use navigation properties , instead of doing a join, but I have been unable to get the right result

so a ( either C#/VB.net )query like

```
var listOfStudents= // get a list with all students , along with each student's subjects
```

Thank you for any help, its such a simple query but I'm kind of stuck

Comment: Why don't you just add another property in your `Student` model that gets his subjects so that the subjects will load automatically?

Answer (score 4):

```
var listOfStudents = db.Student.Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Name = x.StudentName, Subjects = x.StudentsSubjects.Select(y => y.Subject) });
```

Comment: thx...unfortunately this only gives me a list of student names along with their respective ids, it doesn't fetch the subjects :(

Comment: @iAteABug_And_iLiked_it Strange, I just tested it and worked fine for me.

Comment: i'll spend some more time on this project tomorrow to try to get it goingn using the solution above or your solution...thx

Answer (score 2):

If you remove `Id` field from the table `StudentsSubject` then remove this table from the model and update your model, EF will automatically convert this table in two navigational properties `Subjects` and `Students` for `Student` and `Subject` entities respectively.

If you must leave StudentsSubject table schema intact you can use `Include()` method to get both students and their subjects:

```
var students = dbContext.Students.Include("StudentsSubject.Subject")
```

With 'normal' navigation properties you could write the following:

```
var students = dbContext.Students.Include("Subjects")
```

Sometimes you need to assembly large graphs then Include() and lazy loading can affect performance. There is a small trick for this case:

```
// switch off for performance
DbContext.Configuration.AutodetectChangesEnabled = false;

// load root entities   
var roots = dbContext.Parents.Where( root => %root_condition%).ToList();

// load entities one level lower
dbContext.DependentEntities.Where( dependent => dependent.Root%root_condition% && %dependent_condition%).ToList();

// detect changes
dbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

// enable changes detection.
DbContext.Configuration.AutodetectChangesEnabled = true;
```

Now `root.Dependents` collections are filled for `roots`.

Here is the tradeoff between join redundancy (include or join) and several db requests along with the increasing complexity of requests.

With 'includes' data for joined nodes is duplicated so a chain of includes can produce enormous traffic from DB to client.
With the second approach each level requires filtering conditions of all upper levels in Where() and EF generates the query with N-1 joins for the N-th level, but there is no place for redundancy.

As far as I know EF now works fine with Contains() and conditions for parent nodes can be substituted with `Contains()`:

```
// load root entities   
var roots = dbContext.Parents.Where( root => %root_condition%).ToList();

var rootIds = new List<int>( roots.Select( root => root.Id));

// load entities one level lower
dbContext.DependentEntities.Where( dependent => %dependent_condition% && rootIds.Contains( dependent.RootId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

A regular LINQ join should do the trick. Here's a reduced test case:

```vb
Public Class Student
  Public Property Id As String
  Public Property StudentName As String
  Public Property GPA As String
End Class

Public Class StudentsSubject
  Public Property SubjectId As String
  Public Property StudentId As String
  Public Property Id As String
End Class

Public Class Subject
  Public Property Id As String
  Public Property SubjectName As String
End Class

Sub Main()
  Dim students As New List(Of Student)
  students.Add(New Student With {.Id = "1", .GPA = "GPA1", .StudentName = "John"})
  students.Add(New Student With {.Id = "2", .GPA = "GPA2", .StudentName = "Peter"})

  Dim subjects As New List(Of Subject)
  subjects.Add(New Subject With {.Id = "100", .SubjectName = "Maths"})
  subjects.Add(New Subject With {.Id = "200", .SubjectName = "Physics"})

  Dim studentsSubject As New List(Of StudentsSubject)
  studentsSubject.Add(New StudentsSubject With {.Id = "10", .StudentId = "1", .SubjectId = "100"})
  studentsSubject.Add(New StudentsSubject With {.Id = "20", .StudentId = "1", .SubjectId = "200"})
  studentsSubject.Add(New StudentsSubject With {.Id = "30", .StudentId = "2", .SubjectId = "100"})

  Dim listOfStudents = From st In students
                       Join ss In studentsSubject On ss.StudentId Equals st.Id
                       Join sb In subjects On ss.SubjectId Equals sb.Id
                       Select st.StudentName, st.GPA, sb.SubjectName
End Sub
```

Comment: thx for your detailed answer, I'm afraid i'm getting a "the name ss is not in the scope on the left side of equals' error.... :(

Comment: @iAteABug_And_iLiked_it: this example should work in a brand new project. Which version of VS and .NET framework are you working with? I tested with VS 2010 + .NET 4.0 in a brand new console app.

Comment: I'm on VS2012 , with .net 4.5.... maybe I'm doing something wrong...i'll spend some more time on it tomorrow and see if i can find out the issue. thx

Comment: It should be `On st.Id Equals ss.StudentId`, but although you went out of your way to show working code, a linq-to-objects solution is quite different than a linq-to-"sql store" one. For the latter you don't use joins but navigation properties.

Comment: @GertArnold: I don't quite understand what you are saying. The above *is* working code, it was tested in debugger to yield correct results. I never used LINQ-to-SQL - it's impractical for the applications we are building (insurance). So yes, my expertise is based on LINQ-to-objects. However, I can see no reason why it would not work as written, LINQ-to-SQL, meaning there should be no difference in writing the JOIN syntax, which is what OP's question is about.

Comment: Sure, it works. I'm trying to say that linq-to-"SQL" can be much easier than linq to objects. This verbose join syntax is not necessary in general, although it would work. But I'd prefer a solution like Steve's.

Comment: @GertArnold: Oh okay - that makes sense. Thanks for clarification and sorry for misunderstanding. :)